# HTML CSS Как по нажатию кнопки сделать так,чтобы появился блок и чтобы при перефокусировке он не пропадал?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

использую :focus
display:flex;
[image: нажимаю кнопку]

[image: появился блок]

[image: нажимаю другую кнопку/любое место сайта]
[image: блок пропал]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведённом примере триггером того, что блок необходимо показать является `<input type="checkbox">` он скрыт, чтобы не влиять на вёрстку и размещается рядом с любым блоком. Переключение происходит благодаря тегу `label`, который можно разместить где угодно на странице.

```css
.two {
  display: none
}

input#trigger {
  display: none;
}

input#trigger:checked+div {
  display: block;
}

label {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="trigger">Кнопка</label>
<div>
  <div class="one">1</div>
  <input id="trigger" type="checkbox">
  <div class="two">2</div>
  <div class="three">3</div>
</div>
```